# LXML xpath is stripping output of brackets

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I'm trying to scrap SEC financial filings for data. Here is a link to an example table:

```
target_page = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1564408/000156459017022434/R4.htm'
```

In the target_page's source code, a table cell with numeric output is tagged with `<td class="num" ...> <a ..>somevalue</a></td>`  If the value is negative, it is written as `<td class="num" ...> <a ..>(somevalue)</a></td>` (i.e. the absolute value is wrapped in `()` brackets as opposed to being preceeded by a `-`negative sign.

I can easily pull these values out via the following lxml/requests script:

```
from lxlm.html import fromstring
import requests
page =  requests.get(target_page) 
tree = page.fromstring(page.content)
values = tree.xpath('//td[@class="nump"]/text()')
```

My problem:

for some reason `tree.xpath('//td[@class="nump"]/text()')` is only pulling the numbers, and not returning any `()` characters. In the example page I linked one of the values is `(461,827)`, but my code will simply return `461,827`.

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because cells with negative values have a `num` class, not `nump`. You can handle both:

```
//td[@class="nump" or @class="num"]/text()
```

Or:

```
//td[starts-with(@class, "num")]/text()
```

---

And, to avoid having extra newlines in the output, use `.text_content()`:

```
[cell.text_content().strip() for cell in tree.xpath('//td[@class="nump" or @class="num"]')]
```